# Showing a dialog in a thread

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, pygtk

I have a pygtk add which has a gtk.Button() which when pressed has to do a job of lets say 5 seconds. So, the thought of implementing the time-intensive function ***in the*** signal handler as a thread.

First of all, I have added gtk.gdk.threads_init() in the beginning.

My signal handler is **def send_sms()** and in that I have another function **def send_sms_mycantos()** which I call as a thread.

```
threading.Thread(target = self.send_sms_mycantos, args=(phone_no, message_text, username, password)).start()
```

I also have a function which displays dialogs.

```
def dialog_notification(self, message, dialog_type):
    dlg = gtk.MessageDialog(self.window, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, dialog_type, gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE, message)
    dlg.run()
    dlg.destroy()
```

Now, if I call the above function in my thread

```
self.dialog_notification("Message sent successfully", gtk.MESSAGE_INFO)
```

I get this error.

```
SMSSender.py: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.0.
```

Is this the right way to implement threading. What am I doing wrong. The error is like the thread doesn't know that Xserver is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to run `self.dialog_notification()` in the main gtk thread. Just add `gobject.idle_add(self.dialog_notification, args...)` in your thread.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because you are updating the GUI from a thread.

You should use `Gdk.threads_enter()` and `Gdk.threads_leave()` (you must import Gdk) every time that you access to the GUI.

```
def dialog_notification(self, message, dialog_type):
    dlg = gtk.MessageDialog(self.window, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, dialog_type, gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE, message)
    Gdk.threads_enter()
    dlg.run()
    Gdk.threads_leave()

    Gdk.threads_enter()
    dlg.destroy()
    Gdk.threads_leave()
```